# How to write cache friendly polymorphic code in C++?

Tags: c++, caching, polymorphism

I am writing a piece of code with high demands on performance where I need to handle a large number of objects in a polymorphic way. Let's say I have a class A and a class B which is derived from A. I could now create a vector of B:s like this

```
vector<A*> a(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  a[i] = new B();
```

but if n is large (in the order 10^6 or more in my case) this would require very many calls to new and moreover the n objects could potentially be spread out all over my main memory resulting in very poor cache performance. What would be the right way to deal with this situation? I am thinking of doing something like the following to have all the objects in a contiguous memory region.

```
B* b = new B[n];
vector<A*> a(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  a[i] = b + i;
```

but one problem is how to free up the memory allocated by new B[n] if b is not available anymore (but we still have a). I have just learnt that trying

```
delete[] a[0];
```

is not a good idea...

Comment: Perhaps the flyweight design pattern could help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placement new to construct an object at a particular memory location:

```
vector<A*> a(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  a[i] = new(storage + i*object_size) B();
  // and invoke the destructor manually to release the object (assuming A has a virtual destructor!)
  a[i]->~A();
```

But you cannot solve the 'real' problem without giving up the continuous storage: if one object is freed, it will cause a hole in the heap, thus causing high fragmentation over time. You could only keep track of the freed objects and re-use the storage.

Comment: This is a neat solution which I was able to implement straight away and it solves my problem. Thanks! I used malloc and free to allocate and release the memory pointed to by storage. Made it feel like the good old C days ;-)

Comment: when calculating the address you need to care about the alignment requirement of the type. you can use some modulo and it should do it. the difficult part is getting `alignof` portably. there is some C++11 solution i think, and a boost one. and also `std::aligned_storage`.

Answer (score 7):

If you know for sure that those will only be objects of type `B` why not use a parallel vector:

```
vector<B> storage(n);
vector<A*> pointers(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   pointers[i] = &storage[i];
```

Comment: "If you know for sure that those will only be objects of type B": if you know that, you do not have polymorphic objects. The question is specifically about polymorphic objects.

Comment: Yes, this might work, but how do I make it persistent so that the vector "storage" is not automatically deleted once it goes out of scope?

Comment: @Martin: You have to take care of that depending on what you actual program design is. For example, you could declare `storage` first and `pointers` afterwards - then they will be destroyed in right order. Or you could put them both into a struct.

Comment: i think this is actually a good answer because with a slight push toward generalization you realize you are making pools. one pool per type. this can be abstracted with allocators or overloading new per each class, but just making it visible (using vector) could be encapsulated into a manager and it would be very maintainable and neat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all your objects in contiguous memory and, at the same time, avoid using an indirection (a vector of base class pointers), you can use a union-style container, e.g. a vector `boost::variant`. This will, of course, assume that there is a limited and known number of derived classes and that their sizes are comparable. The drawback is that each element of the vector will take as much memory as the biggest derived class, regardless of their actual class (and it also assumes your classes are reasonable cheap to copy). The advantages are that you have contiguous heterogeneous storage of the polymorphic objects, type-safety, and no indirection when accessing elements. Here is a basic example with `boost::variant` and three classes `A`, `B`, `C`, where both `B` and `C` inherit from `A`, and they are all polymorphic (and, of course, this could be much nicer with some sugar-coating and/or something more specialized for your purpose, not `boost::variant` which is not really appropriate for this purpose):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>

struct A {
  int v1;
  A(int aV1 = 0) : v1(aV1) { };
  virtual ~A() { };
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "A print " << v1 << std::endl; };
  struct get_ref {
    typedef A& result_type;
    template <class T>
    A& operator()(T& obj) const { return obj; };
  };
};

struct B : A {
  float f1;
  B(float aF1 = 0.0) : A(42), f1(aF1) { };
  ~B() { };
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "B print " << f1 << std::endl; };
};

struct C : A {
  double d1;
  C(double aD1 = 0.0) : A(42), d1(aD1) { };
  ~C() { };
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "C print " << d1 << std::endl; };
};

int main() {
  typedef boost::variant<A,B,C> value_type;
  typedef std::vector< value_type > vect_type;
  vect_type arr(15);
  int i=0;
  for(;i<5;++i) arr[i] = A(31);
  for(;i<10;++i) arr[i] = B(0.2);
  for(;i<15;++i) arr[i] = C(0.4);

  for(vect_type::iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it)
    boost::apply_visitor(A::get_ref(), *it).print();

  std::cout << "value_type has size of " << sizeof(value_type) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "compared to: sizeof(A)=" << sizeof(A) << " sizeof(B)=" << sizeof(B) << " sizeof(C)=" << sizeof(C) << std::endl;

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll have to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to store the pointers returned from new[] somewhere, and delete[] them later. Another vector, for example.