# Homogeneous container where type is known only at runtime

Tags: c++, optimization, containers

I have a <strike>single-type</strike> collection whose type is known only at runtime. Once the type is defined, it will never change. I'm currently storing pointers to the objects in a vector, like this:

```
std::vector<Animal*> v;
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to store the instances in contiguous memory. My intention is to write a more cache-friendly code and iterating through the container faster.

I could use boost::variant for each vector's element, e.g.,

```
std::vector<boost::variant< Cat, Dog > >
```

but if `sizeof(Dog)` is much bigger than `sizeof(Cat)` then there is a waste of memory in the case where objects are of type `Cat`.

I could also use a Variant of containers:

```
boost::variant< std::vector<Cat>, std::vector<Dog> >
```

but I don't know how iterators would be in this case and if they would introduce more overhead.

Is "vector of pointers approach" the best we can do?

More info: the sizes of the objects are between 50 and 250 bytes and containers length is between 10K and 1M elements, and I have to iterate over the container a million times.

Thank you.

**EDIT**: I found a similar question here (with nice suggestions too): 
[How to write cache friendly polymorphic code in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261027/how-to-write-cache-friendly-polymorphic-code-in-c)

Comment: Does this make any sense "I have a single-type collection whose type is known only at runtime"? Might be my age but it does not

Comment: Maybe he means variant-type collection? It seems like you know the options and trade offs. You just need to decide what it more important for you.

Comment: @EdHeal: I think it means the values in the container are of homogeneous type, but that type is not known at compile time.  Contrast this to a container of heterogeneous types, which is more powerful but not needed here.

Comment: "Once the type is defined, it will never change" --- can you prove that to a compiler?

Comment: @EdHeal I must have expressed myself badly. The comment made by JohnZwinck is exactly what I mean.

Comment: If you're currently using a base class pointer, *and* you'd be happy with a straight subclass vector, then sounds like you only need the `Animal` interface and don't need polymorphism, so could you just have a `std::vector<Animal>` and slice all your elements to it?

Comment: Is there a strict requirement to have all objects in a single container? I would say you best bet is to put all dogs into a `vector<Dog>` and all cats into a `vector<Cat>` and then iterate over both of them seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right - complete rewrite here, and much simpler.

I agree with s3rius that you should still use std::vector. Ideally if you're storing cats you'd use...

```
std::vector<Cat>
```

and if you're storing dogs, you'd like...

```
std::vector<Dog>
```

However, you need run-time polymorphism to choose which case you're dealing with.

One way is (or is inspired by) the strategy design pattern. Define a base class for your interface to those vectors, and have a template class implementing that interface that contains the vector.

```
class Animals_IF
{
  public:
    virtual int size () const = 0;
};

template<typename T> class Animals_Vector
{
  private:
    std::vector<T> store;

  public:
    int size () const;
};

template<typename T> int Animals_Vector<T>::size () const
{
  return store.size ();
}
```

The issue here is that the interface cannot mention `Cat` or `Dog` because it doesn't know the specific type, which is of course why I chose `size` as the example method above.

One solution is to pass values using a `boost::variant` of the possible types, so each of the strategy/wrapper classes can check that the values it gets are the correct type before using them. Wrapping/unwrapping values in the variant could be handled by template methods in the (non-template) base class.

In cases where all that wrapping and unwrapping gets inefficient, you have to determine which case you're dealing with then call through the correct strategy/wrapper type (not the base class). To do that, have a boost::variant of all the strategy/wrapper cases. This doesn't prevent you also having a pointer-to-base-class as well. In fact, wrap both the pointer-to-base-class and the `boost::variant` in a class (with template methods where needed).

```
class Animals_IF
{
  public:
    typedef boost::variant<Cat,Dog>  Animal;

    virtual int size () const = 0;

    template<typename T> void slow_push (const T &p)
    {
      push_ (Animal (p));
    }

  private:
    virtual void slow_push_ (const Animal &p) = 0;
};

template<typename T> class Animals_Vector
{
  public:
    int size () const;

    void fast_push (const T &p);

  private:
    std::vector<T> store;

    void slow_push_ (const Animal &p);
};

template<typename T> int Animals_Vector<T>::size () const
{
  return store.size ();
}

template<typename T> void Animals_Vector<T>::fast_push (const T &p)
{
  store.push (p);
}

template<typename T> void Animals_Vector<T>::slow_push_ (const Animal &p)
{
  const T* item = boost::get<T> (&p);

  if (T)  store.push (*item);
  //  else throw?
}

class Animals
{
  public:
    int size () const
    {
      //  null check needed?
      return ptr->size ();
    }

    template<typename T> void slow_push (const T &p)
    {
      //  null check needed?
      ptr->slow_push (p);
    }

    template<typename T> void fast_push (const T &p)
    {
      Animals_Vector<T> *lptr = boost::get<T> (&store);
      if (lptr)  lptr->fast_push (p);
      //  else throw?
    }

  private:
    Animals_IF*  ptr;
    boost::variant<Animals_Vector<Cat>,Animals_Vector<Dog>>  store;
};
```

If there's nothing that the shared interface can really provide (because every method needs to pass values, and wrapping/unwrapping as variants is unacceptable) the whole strategy thing is unnecessary. Just have a boost::variant of different std::vector types.

Also, the `fast_push` above won't be fast because a `push` is too simple to benefit - the idea is that the approach is faster for complex methods that can avoid repeated run-time type checking by getting it done once, up front.

BTW - nice question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to turn my comment into an answer.

I would say you best bet is to put all dogs into a `vector<Dog>` and all cats into a `vector<Cat>` and then iterate over both of them separately. That way you can keep each vector optimally packed.

With some CRTP you can automate it in order to make it easy to add more Animals without trouble.

Some example:

```
template <typename T>
class Container{
public:
    static std::vector<T> m_elements; //static vector will contain animals

    //overloaded operator new adds the Animal to m_elements
    void* operator new(size_t){
        m_elements.push_back( T{} );
        return &m_elements[m_elements.size() - 1];
    }
};

template <typename T> std::vector<T> Container<T>::m_elements;

//some example animals
class Dog : public Container<Dog>{
public:
    std::string woof;

    Dog( char* s = "woof" ){
        woof = s;
    }
};

class Cat : public Container<Cat>{
public:
    std::string meow;

    Cat( char* s = "meow" ){
        meow = s;
    }
};

int main(){

    new Dog( "woof" );
    new Dog( "rrawoof" );
    new Cat( "meow" );
    new Cat( "meweeow" );

    //easy iteration
    for( auto dog : Dog::m_elements )
        std::cout << dog.woof << "\n";

    for( auto cat : Cat::m_elements )
        std::cout << cat.meow << "\n";

    std::cout << "end";
}
```

Whether it's a good idea to overload `new` or not is a different question, but it's nice for show.

Comment: Really nice answer. I couldn't have said it myself. No, really. I didn't even have a real answer.